# Ted Cruz's "natural-born" citizenship qualification for the Presidential run

Tags: united-states, president, immigration, republican-party, citizenship

There's a commotion about [Ted Cruz getting sued](http://thehill.com/blogs/ballot-box/presidential-races/269281-trump-supporters-file-federal-lawsuit-challenging-cruzs) <sup>(1)</sup> per [Article II, Section 1 of the Constitution](http://www.archives.gov/exhibits/charters/constitution_transcript.html) <sup>(2)</sup> on the basis of **that being exactly what disqualifies his eligibility to run for President of the United States of America**.

An [accepted answer here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/8752/how-is-it-that-ted-cruz-can-run-for-the-u-s-presidency-seeing-as-he-was-born-in/8755#8755) <sup>(3)</sup> on **Politics.SE** refers to the [Acquisition of U.S. Citizenship by a Child Born Abroad](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/legal/travel-legal-considerations/us-citizenship/Acquisition-US-Citizenship-Child-Born-Abroad.html) <sup>(4)</sup> and this being exactly what satisfied his mother's eligibility qualification at that time.

### Per Referenced Material

Based on the above (and below) references, some items just seem to need to be verified to confirm authenticity and legitimacy of the qualification ***under these guidelines thereof:***

- Confirm he's 35 years old when running
- Confirm his residence in the US for at least 14 years prior to running

  - *(Has he been living in the US for 14 years)*
- Confirm he is a natural-born citizen

  - *(Based on his mother's status at the time of his birth)*
  - *(Confirm accuracy of his mother's birth and citizenship)*

    - <strike>If his ***mother was over 14 years old at the time of his birth***, confirm his mother was physically present residing in the US for a period of 5 years</strike>
    - <strike>If his ***mother was under 14 years old at the time of his birth*** confirm his mother was physically present and residing in the US for a period of 10 years.</strike>
    - Confirm his mother (U.S. citizen parent) was physically present in the United States or one of its outlying possessions for 10 years prior to his (Ted Cruz) birth, at least five of which were after the age of 14.

### Question

Can anyone answer any part of this with any **referenced proof** *(in either direction to prove or disprove)* and/or **reference other laws** which may qualify or disqualify the eligibility of Ted Cruz to run for President of the United States of America?

---

### References

- [Lawsuit Against Cruz in Federal Court](http://thehill.com/blogs/ballot-box/presidential-races/269281-trump-supporters-file-federal-lawsuit-challenging-cruzs)<sup>(1)</sup>
- [Article II, Section 1 of the Constitution](http://www.archives.gov/exhibits/charters/constitution_transcript.html)<sup>(2)</sup>
- [SE Accepted Answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/8752/how-is-it-that-ted-cruz-can-run-for-the-u-s-presidency-seeing-as-he-was-born-in/8755#8755)<sup>(3)</sup>
- [Acquisition of U.S. Citizenship by a Child Born Abroad](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/legal/travel-legal-considerations/us-citizenship/Acquisition-US-Citizenship-Child-Born-Abroad.html)<sup>(4)</sup>

Comment: The only "referenced proof" possible for the "natural-born citizen" part is an interpretation by the Supreme Court of the meaning of that phrase in the Constitution.  Such a ruling does not exist.

Comment: "Confirm his mother physically resided in the US for a period of five years before birth" It's actually that his mother was physically present in the US for a period of ten years, including five years after she turned 14.

Comment: "Can anyone put this to rest" = yes. The courts can. If and when this issue gets to the courts.

Comment: @blip: Assuming that someone has standing, and the courts don't consider it a political question.

Comment: Funny how Trump, a vocal birther who espoused Obama's supposed Kenyan birth as indicating ineligibility, hasn't been all over Cruz on this issue. Black Democrats with a US birth certificate are suspect, whereas half-Latino Republicans without one are fine?  Interesting....

Comment: @MichaelBroughton - funny how people like you ignore mountains of evidence if it proves their pet theories wrong: ["Donald Trump Hammers Away At Ted Cruz's Citizenship"](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/donald-trump-ted-cruz-citizenship_us_5692aaece4b0a2b6fb707f73) - this is Huff Post, not Fox News, even

Comment: Thanks for the correction - that aspect hasn't got much airplay up here. Dunno why you need to toss in the "people like you" and "pet theories"  cr@p though, as if you know me at all. But some people (you can decide if that includes you or not) can't help but make everything personal I guess...

Comment: @MichaelBroughton: Note that Donald Trump has not yet provided his complete birth certificate to the public.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is it that Ted Cruz can run for the U.S. presidency seeing as he was born in Calgary?](http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/8752/how-is-it-that-ted-cruz-can-run-for-the-u-s-presidency-seeing-as-he-was-born-in)

Comment: @JUICED_IT - You're right, you did link to that question.  I hadn't noticed that.  In that case, I'm not sure what the difference between this question and that one is.  Are you just asking *"Is Cruz actually more than 35 years old?  Has he actually lived in the US for 14+ years? Etc.?"* - in other words, "Is he **actually** qualified?"

Comment: @Bobson Yes, basically at the time I wrote the question I was asking if anyone could confirm the items I listed as bullet points and/or sub-bullet points per my interpretation of those items being the ones which could disqualify someone for running for POTUS with referenced proof.

Comment: @JUICED_IT - Got it.  I'm not sure anyone here would be able to answer the question (and you're right about it not really being relevant any more), but I've retracted the close vote.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [Wikipedia - Ted Cruz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ted_Cruz):

> Several lawsuits and ballot challenges asserting that Cruz is ineligible to become U.S. president have been filed. No lawsuit or challenge has been successful, and in February 2016, the Illinois Board of Elections ruled in Cruz's favor, stating, "The candidate is a natural born citizen by virtue of being born in Canada to his mother who was a U.S. citizen at the time of his birth."

The reference cited in the Wikipedia post says:

> Merda, Chad (February 3, 2016). "[Illinois election board: Ted Cruz is a natural-born citizen](https://web.archive.org/web/20160204093102/http://national.suntimes.com/national-world-news/7/72/2541002/ted-cruz-illinois-natural-born-citizen/). *[Chicago Sun-Times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago_Sun-Times)*. Chicago, Illinois. Archived from [the original](http://national.suntimes.com/national-world-news/7/72/2541002/ted-cruz-illinois-natural-born-citizen) on February 4, 2016. Retrieved February 4, 2016. "The candidate is a natural born citizen by virtue of being born in Canada to his mother who was a U.S. citizen at the time of his birth," the board said. It pointed out that Cruz "did not have to take any steps to go through a naturalization process at some point after birth" and therefore "further discussion on this issue is unnecessary."

Comment: I'd like to know who downvoted this answer—the question went unanswered for years and this is an answer and checked off as resolved now. This is exactly what this community should want so if you downvote, it does no good to stay silent regarding whatever issue you see, etc. I'd like the opportunity to pacify your concern downvoter so let me know what the problem is in this particular instance. You've had ample time to vote to close and let the community speak, or flag a mod to take action otherwise. Don't stay silent now if you see a problem here and step forward and speak up.

Comment: @The'BernieSanders'Party - Realistically, the question is on an issue that mostly only exists because people *want* to exist. So "-1 - I don't want this to be true" votes are to be expected, and unless stated otherwise in a comment, that's what we all know happened here.

Comment: If a rule exists because it exists, then the rule should be enforced or else it makes no point to have the rule in the first place. If it is not clear about US citizens giving birth to a child in another country and that child trying to be the leader of a country which they were not born, I guess some people that really don't care about that rule and those that put it in place and their reasons why or two different perspectives. I'd say based on the votes on this now and the comment above that *people mostly do care* about that for maybe for some of those same reasons mentioned.