# Can the POTUS be the monarch of the UK at the same time?

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, president, monarchy

A tweet on my timeline caught my interest today:

> Prince Harry's kids will be Americans. What if one grows up to be president and is in line for the throne at the same time? Brits are playing long-ball here, but it's a smart move. They want America back and this is how they'll do it.
>
> <sub>[—Greg Pollowitz on *Twitter*](https://twitter.com/GPollowitz/status/935137064068308993)</sub>

Is there any legal barrier in either the UK or the USA which stipulate that the President of the United States cannot be the Monarch of the United Kingdom, or vice versa?

Comment: the POTUS must be born in the USA, and that's not a given yet.

Comment: @dandavis AFAIK, the POTUS must merely be a natural born US citizen, which you automatically get if one of your parents is American.

Comment: And least in the context of dual citizenship, it seems OK: https://classroom.synonym.com/can-dual-citizenship-holder-president-us-15680.html

Comment: Re: "born in USA vs. natural born citizen", [we have a question on that](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/8752/11249) :-)

Comment: There are laws against holding dual office but they may not apply to UK royalty as an office, only US govt roles

Comment: Is there a question on whether the Emoluments Clause is retroactive?

Comment: For amusement value, this is in the Hot Network Questions right now: [As a queen, what must I do to take the son of my husband's dynasty out of succession line?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/322080/as-a-queen-what-must-i-do-to-take-the-son-of-my-husbands-dynasty-out-of-succes)

Comment: @user4012 The Perth Agreement https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perth_Agreement was an attempt to ensure that the crowned Monarch of the UK holds multiple "offices" for the foreseeable future.

Comment: If Harry were to become first in line to become monarch, it would likely lead to a massive controversy as no one is really sure who his dad is (because he looks like the officer his mom had an affair with). So it just as likely he would get passed over for not being a descendant of Rollo, as every other English/British monarch has been.

Comment: It's worth noting that Harry is currently 6th in line. Any child he has will be 7th in line, but they will get bumped back down the queue when any descendant of Prince William has a child. The odds that any descendant of Harry will get anywhere near the throne  are vanishingly small.

Comment: This Twitter quote is a completely baseless conspiracy theory.  That much should be obvious from the fact that Greg Pollowitz is not a mind-reader and obviously has no legitimate sources leading him to his conclusion.  I don't think it is helpful to spread the conspiracy theory.  Also, the fact that these hypothetical children have monarchical ties would likely hurt their chances of a successful presidential run.  Also, these children don't even exist.  Also, where is the evidence that literally any child born in the U.S. wasn't conceived as part of a sinister plot to control the White House?

Comment: @John. It's not a conspiracy theory; it's a *joke*.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I can't speak to requirements for the UK monarchy, but on the US side, it appears to be legally *possible* for someone **in line to the throne** to become President.  The only constitutional requirements are:

> No Person except a natural born Citizen, or a Citizen of the United States, at the time of the Adoption of this Constitution, shall be eligible to the Office of President; neither shall any Person be eligible to that Office who shall not have attained to the Age of thirty five Years, and been fourteen Years a Resident within the United States. [[ref]](http://constitutionus.com/#a2s1c5)

and

> No person shall be elected to the office of the President more than twice, and no person who has held the office of President, or acted as President, for more than two years of a term to which some other person was elected President shall be elected to the office of the President more than once. [[ref]](http://constitutionus.com/#x22)

Obviously, there's no guarantee of being elected, and the nature of the situation practically writes the attack ads from opponents (similar to criticisms of [Kennedy about being a Catholic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_F._Kennedy#1960_presidential_election) and thus answerable to the Pope).

---

However, it's a very different story when it comes to actually **inheriting** the crown while in office.  Article I, Section 9, clause 8 of the Constitution (also called the Emoluments Clause) states

> No Title of Nobility shall be granted by the United States: And no Person holding any Office of Profit or Trust under them, shall, without the Consent of the Congress, accept of any present, Emolument, Office, or Title, of any kind whatever, from any King, Prince, or foreign State. [[ref]](http://constitutionus.com/#a1s9c8)

I think everyone can agree that becoming the King or Queen of the UK would constitute "accepting an Office or Title from a foreign State".  Thus, the POTUS/heir would require Congressional approval to accept the crown.  Without it, they could choose to resign as POTUS or abdicate the crown, but they could not hold both.

The same logic may apply to being named Crown Prince/ess (due to the death or abdication of a prior claimant).  The person in question would still be the [heir apparent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heir_apparent), but would be unable to receive any of the associated lands or titles until Congress approved or they left office.

It's also worth noting that none of these requirements are unique to the President.  *Anyone* holding any elected or appointed office in the US would have the same restrictions on taking the crown without Congressional approval.

Comment: Junior royals in the UK also accept Titles from a foreign state. For example, Kate became the Dutchess of Cambridge. The residency requirement would also eliminate most royal family members. For example, Princess Charlotte of Cambridge and Prince George of Cambridge each have aristocratic titles despite not even being in grade school yet. I don't see any way the one can be a royal and a President. I'm also not sure that the original U.S. citizenship of the parent would survive a royal marriage, I think the marriage amounts to a renunciation of U.S. citizenship so the kids are not US citizens.

Comment: There are a couple of the seven grounds for loss of U.S. citizenship that would probably apply to someone marrying a heir to the British throne. https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1481

Comment: @ohwilleke There's nothing in the law preventing a title-holder from being elected, just elected officials *gaining* titles. That said, you're right that if the children were raised in the U.K., they wouldn't have the years to qualify. But they could theoretically be raised as Americans in the US, who just happen to be a ways down the line of succession, and then inherit through an unlikely series of events. It'd make for a good plot for a novel or movie.

Comment: Even absent the enoulements clause, everyone with a title of nobility owes duties as well as receiving privileges to the sovereign which would cause them to lose U.S. citizenship per 8 USC 1481. Adult royals are IIRC, ex officio military officers as well which would also implicated 8 USC 1481.

Comment: There are precedents for a POTUS in the line of succession: For example both Presidents Bush are [13th cousins of the Queen](http://www.nytimes.com/1988/07/05/us/bush-they-say-is-indeed-a-connecticut-yankee-from-king-henry-s-court.html) and therefore have a defined place in line -- several hundred places down, but still a lot closer than most of us.

Comment: @ohwilleke You should write up all that in your own answer, rather than leave it in comments.  You certainly may be right, but I'm not going to edit this answer to address loss of citizenship.

Comment: @ohwilleke expatriating acts only cause loss of citizenship if undertaken with intent to lose citizenship.  The administrative presumption of lack of intent would not apply to someone becoming head of state of a foreign country, but as far as I understand it, there still must be intent.  As far as I know, nobody ever determined whether King Bhumibol lost his US citizenship on becoming king.

Comment: @Bobson it was called [King Ralph](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0102216/).

Comment: @RobK - Why am I not surprised it already existed?   Admittedly, I was thinking "and became a politician" when I wrote that, which doesn't match the movie, but I didn't actually include it.

Comment: What about the monarch of the UK becoming president? In this case the title was bestowed before entering the election. Could the British king, who happens to be a US citizen; run for president?

Comment: @DohnJoe - I think it would be hard for the British monarch to satisfy the "and been fourteen Years a Resident within the United States" requirement.

Answer (score 3):

I would say that in the strict reading of the law, this scenario would be possible (provided that Harry's line becomes Heir Apparent in some fashion.  Presently they are not.).  If challenged, Originalism interpretation of the constitution might prevent that as the line was specifically carved out in a fashion to prevent this from happening, it might prevent royalty with dual citizenship in the U.S. from becoming President.  Additionally, the prospective politician will have to reside in the United States territories for 14 years.

Additionally, Prince Harry is currently fifth in line for the Throne.  This would mean that Prince Charles (Father), Prince William (Brother), Prince George (Nephew), and Princess Charlotte (Niece) will all be unable to become regent.  Assuming no more offspring from William, This means that any off spring from Harry would be sixth in line and has a long way to go (Or a lot of Disney villain plots to enact) before they will get that close.

Theoretically, such a situation would actually give America more power over Britain than the reverse, as POTUS is both Head of Government and Head of State where as the Monarch is only a Head of State.  The Monarch of England does have the legal authority to dissolve Parliament, so that special relationship that American and England has will have a lot more special of a relationship in America's finger as now American can keep doing that until such time that the President/Monarch has a favorable PM.

But since the Prime Minister and Parliament get to set rules for being King/Queen, they can say that the Monarch must renounce dual citizenship before ascent to the throne, or bar the situation out right.  After all, the last thing Britain wants is to lose power to us colonials.  Brexit will be a living memory and no one is going to want to get rid out of toxic relationship with a ruling body from across the sea only to be brought into another one that quickly.

Answer (score -1):

#### Legal obstacles

The [United States constitution](https://www.archives.gov/founding-docs/constitution-transcript) says in Article I, Section 9 (the [Foreign Emoluments Clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Title_of_Nobility_Clause)):

> No Title of Nobility shall be granted by the United States: And no Person holding any Office of Profit or Trust under them, shall, without the Consent of the Congress, accept of any present, Emolument, Office, or Title, of any kind whatever, from any King, Prince, or foreign State.

So someone can't be named monarch of the United Kingdom while president without the explicit consent of Congress.  They would have to inherit before becoming president.

#### Does it matter?

Of course, the president can't even sign a binding treaty without the concurrence of two thirds of the Senators (Article II, Section 2, the [Treaty Clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_Clause)) much less surrender sovereignty.  To surrender sovereignty would take a constitutional amendment, which requires the acquiescence of at least three quarters of the states ([Article V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_Five_of_the_United_States_Constitution)).

I suppose as Commander in Chief, a president could coordinate with UK invasion forces and move the US armed forces out of the way.  However, the [last time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Revolutionary_War) that the UK sent troops to the US didn't end so well.  And they had official support from the sovereign then.  Not to mention that the UK then had almost five times the population of what would become the US but now has about a quarter.

#### An alternative

A better plan might be to have a lot of kids, each of whom had more kids.  In several generations, they could take over the state legislatures and deliver the US to the UK.  There are no legal impediments to that.  Once sovereignty was surrendered, the kids could become the new nobility:  Dukes and Duchesses of the states; Earls and Countesses of the counties; Marquesses and Marquessas, Viscounts and Viscountesses, Barons and Baronesses, and Baronets and Baronetesses of municipalities.  That would probably be easier if they focused on royal bastards rather than legitimate children.

Twenty kids with one woman is a lot.  The record is sixty-nine in twenty-seven pregnancies.  Supposedly Genghis Khan fathered over a thousand children and more recently there have been examples of men with [hundreds of children](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_people_with_the_most_children).  So if speed is important, ditch the monogamy.  The royal sperm donor should have bought the Playboy mansion instead.

Of course, they could skip the sperm donation and go straight to the bribing of potential state legislators.  That could be a lot quicker.

Comment: Does the war of 1812 not count?

Comment: There may be a legal quibble about being dubbed a King or Queen.  Who is it that is bestowing this title? The King or Queen *is* the state. Is it actually granted by anyone or anything, legally speaking?  One might have to consult a scholar on the legal technicalities of this title in the UK (and elsewhere), and then conjecture how American courts would interpret them.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy. Legally speaking, the title comes from God, I believe.

Comment: If a foreign power were to put an agent as POTUS, I doubt they would put a known high level official of their own in place. Instead, they better opt for a person they can control within one of the large parties so that person can control its lower level politicians. That's how the US does it, that's how the Russians do it. (mostly in smaller countries, of course)